# How Compare and Extract equal values from Nested Dictionary and Append the equal values to a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtable

I have the following function responsible to generate a nested dictionary with integer keys that works inside a for loop, and I want to create a updated list when equal values are found:

```
# The number of times I want to run
n = 2
# Number of Loops
count = 0
# Init the Hash Table
castar_hash = {}

def run_discrete_time(start, path, count):
    '''
    Create or Update the Nested Dic, look for equal values and append
    a new list based on the 'path' input

    Args:

       start (list)
       path  (list)
       count (int)

    Vars:

        start = A simple list with one element
        path  = A list of Tuples
        count = The atual Loop Interaction
    '''
    # Inserted the 0 because the "discrete time" will init at 0
    path_list.insert(0, start)

    time_run = list(range(0, len(path_list)+1))
    hash = {t:p for t,p in zip(time_run,path_list)}

    #* Create a new Dic Key
    value_list = ['value', str(count)]
    value = "".join(value_list)
    castar_hash.update({value:hash})

    print(f'\nThe time steps is: {time_run}')
    print(f'The Hash table is: {castar_hash}\n')
    '''
    Need the code here to find the equal values
    in the castar_hash and append to a updated list
    '''
    return updated_list

def main():
    for _ in range(n):
        '''
        some code here who picks the start and path from a deque
        already implemented (see the inputs bellow)
        '''
        count += 1
        run_discrete_time(start, path, count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Let me explain how the function works with inputs**: Considering that the loop will run 2 times (since the number of times "n" is 2), for the first call, considering the input:

```
run_discrete_time([4, 6], [(4, 5), (4, 4),(4, 3),(5, 3),(6, 3),
                  (7, 3), (8, 3), (8, 2), (8, 1),(9, 1)],
                  count)
```

The generated nested dic will be:

```
castar_hash = {'value1': {0:(4, 6), 1:(4, 5), 2:(4, 4), 3:(4, 3), 
                          4:(5, 3), 5:(6, 3), 6:(7, 3), 7:(8, 3),
                          8:(8, 2), 9:(8, 1), 10:(9, 1)},
```

For the second loop with inputs:

```
run_discrete_time([1, 6], [(2, 6), (4, 4), (4, 6),(4, 5), (4, 4),
                  (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (8, 1), (8, 3), (9, 3)],
                  count)
```

The updated nest dic will now be:

```
castar_hash = {'value1': {0:(4, 6), 1:(4, 5), 2:(4, 4), 3:(4, 3), 
                          4:(5, 3), 5:(6, 3), 6:(7, 3), 7:(8, 3),
                          8:(8, 2), 9:(8, 1), 10:(9, 1)}, 
               'value2': {0:(1, 6), 1:(2, 6), 2:(4, 4), 3:(4, 6), 
                          4:(4, 5), 5:(4, 4), 6:(4, 3), 7:(5, 3),
                          8:(6, 3), 9:(8, 1), 10:(8, 3), 11:(9,3)}}
```

**My question is:** What is the best and most efficient way to extract the equal values in the nested dics for every loop (considering that I can have more than two)? I'm struggling a lot to find a solution for that.

For example, the repeated values in the 'value2' dic is **2:(4, 4)** and **9:(8, 1)** (in relation to the 'value1' dic), and I would like to return a new list updated as (4,4) inserted in the index 2, and (8,1) at index 9, for example:

```
#The Path List of Tuples inputed at the second loop
path = [(2, 6), (4, 4), (4, 6),(4, 5), (4, 4),
        (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (8, 1), (8, 3), (9, 3)]
#The New Updated Path List that I want to return since
#the method finded equals values compared to the 'value1' dic:
new_path = [(2, 6), (4, 4), (4, 4) (4, 6),(4, 5), (4, 4),
            (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (8, 1), (8, 1), (8, 3),
            (9, 3)]
```

Comment: what is your question exactly and what is path and how are you generating it?

Comment: Hi deadshot, the path is a list generated in another function. He is inserted into a deque and in the function above I just pop the list out. Regarding the question, I want to update this list if the values on the dict keys are the same.

Comment: how to find the index for inserting?

Comment: Can't you create a list of tuples for every integer key? In this case you can perhaps flatten your nested dict to just one level. But I am not sure of your problem statement.. just a thought

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I need to use the dics, most of this because the speed ( lookups in dictionaries are amortized O(1)). In this example I'm using only 2 loops, but for 200 loops with 200 list lookups things will be harder for me.